# Jquery Mobile page transitions on desktop site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to use the "turn" effect found [here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) on a regular desktop site I'm building.  I DO NOT want to use the jquery mobile library.  I want to know if I can replicate this effect using regular jquery/css3/html5 with regular hyperlinks on a desktop site.

Please note:  I am not using AJAX or PHP on my site.  I want everything to be solely made up of jQuery/CSS3/HTML/Javascript.  This means that it is not a one-page site.  There are a bunch of different html documents paired together with hyperlinks like a traditional website, and I want to know if theres a way to use javascript to, perhaps, preload the other pages so they are ready for the animation when clicked.

I'm looking for the same exact functionality as the link I've provided.  This means animate when clicked, reverse animate when going back, and preloading the pages so they're ready.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: pre-loading the other pages so they are ready for the animation will require AJAX, unless you include all pages on the same .html page.

Answer (score 0):

http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php

That link has some of the same transitions (including turn) but applied to smaller elements. This uses css3 transitions. I'm not sure if jQuery uses CSS3 or straight javascript to apply the transforms, but in any case the effect will be the same (just not compatible on ie8 or lower)...

And, re: "preloading the pages so they're ready." what's the difference between this and having all the content on one page? It sounds like you should be structuring your site with PHP templates and `include()` rather than HTML and jQuery.

Comment: jQuery Mobile uses CSS classes to create its transitions. The JS used is just to cue-up the correct classes at the correct time.